# Step Eval Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have been trying to find a method to do a "step" eval. Where I call the a function and it evaluates the most nested list for common lisp.

For example:

```
'(+ 2 (+ 3 4))
; would eval to:
'(+ 2 7)
```

In that example it just evaluated 3 + 4 and stopped right there. It did not continue on to eval 2 + 7 like what lisp would normally do.

So I want the code to find the most nested list and eval the most nested list, without evaluating the whole list.

For example:

```
'(+ 2 3 4 5 (+ 4 5 (- 5 6) 1 (+ 10 8 5 (- 10 11))) 10 7)
```

It would find the most nested list, `(- 10 11)`, and eval it so:

```
'(+ 2 3 4 5 (+ 4 5 (- 5 6) 1 (+ 10 8 5 -1)) 10 7)
```

Again it only evaluates once, and does not evaluate the whole list at once.

Does anybody know how you could go about this to make a step evaluation for the most nested list? To use eval or something to execute the most nested part of the list without `eval`ing the whole list at once? The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to evaluate the most nested list and then put it back together. I don't know how to approach this. Please enlighten me on how a master lisper would do this.

Comment: The expression is a nested list. Just walk this nested list and if it is a *terminal* list, call eval. You need first to learn how to traverse a nested list with a function.

Comment: I'v managed to write a function that can get to the most nested part, but I don't know how I would put it back together. Maybe I'm just visualizing this wrong or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of evaluation is left-to-right, so it is not exactly right to evaluate the deepest nested list if you want to emulate Common Lisp's behaviour.

You rather have to evaluate the first nested form first.  Assuming well-formed input:

```
(defun step-eval (form)
  (let ((sub-index (position-if #'listp form)))
    (if sub-index
        ;; there is a deeper list to step first
        (append (subseq form 0 sub-index)
                (list (step-eval (nth sub-index form)))
                (subseq form (1+ sub-index)))
        ;; no deeper list, eval this
        (eval form))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Us use [`step`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_step.htm):

```
(step (+ 2 (+ 3 4)))
step 1 --> (+ 2 (+ 3 4))
Step 1 [4]> step
step 2 --> 2
Step 2 [5]> step
step 2 ==> value: 2
step 2 --> (+ 3 4)
Step 2 [6]> step
step 3 --> 3
Step 3 [7]> step
step 3 ==> value: 3
step 3 --> 4
Step 3 [8]> step
step 3 ==> value: 4
step 2 ==> value: 7
step 1 ==> value: 9
9
```

It doesn't do exactly what you want but it is pretty close. The reason is that Common Lisp is required to evaluate the expressions in exactly the order the stepper does it.

Comment: Hi, which implementation is this?